# No such module FirebaseStorage

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, firebase-storage

I am working on an iOS project in swift 5 in Xcode 11.6 using cocoapods. Whenever I try to build it fails with the error message 'No Such Module FirebaseStorage'. I have tried deintegrating and installing several times. Below is the pod file I'm using. If I looking in the pods directory in the project folder, I can see a firebasestorage folder. I have also attached my header search path under the build settings for the workspace. [header search path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVV1P.png)

```
Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.6'

#install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

target 'project' do
  # use_modular_headers!
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'MessageKit'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore' 
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
 end

  # Pods for project



  target 'projectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'projectUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if Gem::Version.new('8.0') >
           Gem::Version.new(config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'])
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '8.0'
      end
    end
end

end
```

I was wondering what might be causing this issue?

Comment: What is the cocoa tag for?

Comment: @ElTomato removed, I just wanted the cocoa pods tag

Comment: Are you actually building or just seeing the module error in the Xcode UI?  An actual build may need to be invoked to prime the Xcode module cache.